# Why is the MongoDB aggregation framework with the $out operator generating network traffic?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, network-traffic, mongodb-mms

I have an aggregation pipeline ending with the `$out` operator to write the results to another collection. It works as expected but when I look to the network traffic metrics in MMS, I see the operation generates an extra 180 Kb/s of out traffic from the primary server.

I assumed that the `$out` operator makes the aggregation pipeline to work internally in the server, so no in nor out traffic should happen. So how is this extra traffic being generated?

The pipeline stages are `$match -> $project -> $project -> $out`, and I'm running it directly in the primary server of a 3 node cluster.

Thanks!

Comment: primary server, as in replication? You have just answered your own question

Comment: @Sammaye It would make sense if the out network traffic was generated in the secondary, because the primary would be fetching the data for the aggregation pipeline from the secondary. But that's not the case.

Comment: $out requires a write, aggregation collections are replicated, no matter what happens you have to write to the primary and have that repicated across

Comment: @Sammaye right, of course... Now the only thing I don't understand is why I don't see the same inbound traffic spike in the secondary server.

Comment: What tool are you using to monitor this? Are you monitoring the calling thread that is actually handing data back out to the external source?

Comment: I'm using MMS to monitor the cluster, so I suppose that it's showing the total network usage of the whole MongoDB process in each server.

Comment: I haven't used MMS in a while but I believe it does just show total network usage (or at least did when I last used it), I pesonally use a app like new relic which can show each nework interface and its usage